# Call Directory Extension for Objective-C app is not identifying callers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, callkit

I'm trying to add a Call Directory Extension to an existing Objective-C iOS app.

Creating the extension was straight-forward using `Xcode -> File -> New -> Target`, selecting `Call Directory Extension` and configuring it for Objective-C and the existing project. A new scheme for the extension has also successfully been created.

The extension's `CallDirectoryHandler.h` and `CallDirectoryHandler.m` files have been created automatically and currently I just want to test the general concept by hardcoding a phone number from a real device into it.

That real device has a number with a format like this:

```
+49 176 12345678
```

So far I've only commented out the automatically generated code referring to blocking numbers (which I don't want to do) and changed the phone numbers and strings in the code for identifying numbers.

The code looks like this:

```
- (void)addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
    CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber allPhoneNumbers[] = { 4917612345678, 4917612345679 };
    NSArray<NSString *> *labels = @[ @"XYZ Dev-Test", @"Test Number" ];
    NSUInteger count = (sizeof(allPhoneNumbers) / sizeof(CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber));
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = allPhoneNumbers[i];
        NSString *label = labels[i];
        [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:label];
    }
}

- (void)addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
    CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumbersToAdd[] = { 4917612345678 };
    NSArray<NSString *> *labelsToAdd = @[ @"XYZ Dev-Test Inc" ];
    NSUInteger countOfPhoneNumbersToAdd = (sizeof(phoneNumbersToAdd) / sizeof(CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber));

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < countOfPhoneNumbersToAdd; i += 1) {
        CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumbersToAdd[i];
        NSString *label = labelsToAdd[i];
        [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:label];
    }
}
```

Again, this is automatically generated code and I only changed the phone numbers and strings in it.

I have enabled the extension under `Settings -> Phone -> Call blocking & identification` and have toggled the switch many times already.

However when I call the phone from that number, it is never identified. I've already tried the following number formats in the code:

```
+4917612345678
4917612345678
017612345678
17612345678
```

I noticed that the iPhone 6 plus with iOS 11.1 that I use for testing displays the incoming call's number as `0176 12345678`.

I also tried the following:

- reset all settings on the phone
- delete the app from the device
- run the app from Xcode with the scheme of the main app
- run the app again with the scheme of the extension
- select my main app in the dialog asking to choose an app

Nonetheless the number identification doesn't work. I'm not even sure the app extension is executed, because I can't debug it with break points and the NSLog entries I've added for testing didn't appear in the console.

Is there an important step that I am missing here?

Comment: You supply the number as a 64 bit integer; so just an Int64 with the value 4917612345678.  Debugging the extension is tricky. You need to use the “attach to process” option in Xcode, specify the name of your callkit extension.

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers supplied via the extension must always be prefixed by the country's dialing code (49 in your case). And if the number incoming to the phone is `0176 12345678`, you probably should try using `49017612345678` (note the zero).